# How to transition from a prerecorded video to real time video?

Tags: matlab, video-processing

I have come up with an algorithm on Matlab, that permits me to recognize hand gestures on prerecorded videos. Now, I would like to run the same code but for real time video this time, I am not sure how to do it after putting these 2 lines:

vid=videoinput('winvideo',1);

preview(vid);

(real time video is on)

I am thinking about a loop : while the video is on, snap repeatedly some images in order to analyze them.

for k=1:numFrames

my code is applied here.

So, I would like to know how to make this transition from prerecorded videos to real time video.

Your help in this so much appreciated!

Comment: Did you use an online or a batch algorithm which for recognition? How many frames did it use to recognize the gesture?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to first verify whether you can perform acquisition + gesture recognition in real-time using your algorithm. for that, first read video frames in a loop and render or save them and compute the reading and rendering overhead of a single frame say t1. Also compute the time taken by your algorithm to process one image say t2. The throughput(no. of frames process per second) of your system will be

throughput  = 1/(t1 + t2)

It is important to know how many frames you need to process a gesture. First, try  to compute the minimum no. of images that you need to identify a gesture in a given time and then verify in real-time whether you can process the same no. of images in the same time.